# Using TYPE instruction assembly MASM x86

Tags: assembly, addition, masm, x86-16, cpu-registers

I'm still learning assembly and I got confused when I reach this portion of a code:

```
add SI, TYPE word
```

Since I don't quite get what the TYPE instruction stands for there, what exacly are we adding to SI?
If someone can ilustrate me how this works assuming SI set 0 before reaching add I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

From the MASM 6.1 Programmer's Guide:

The `SIZEOF` and `TYPE` operators, when applied to a type, return the size of an integer of that type.
The size attribute associated with each data type is:

```
Data Type      Bytes
--------------------
BYTE, SBYTE    1
WORD, SWORD    2
DWORD, SDWORD  4
FWORD          6
QWORD          8
TBYTE          10
```

---

Side note: For arrays and strings, `SIZEOF` and `TYPE` are not equivalent. `SIZEOF` will give you the total size of the array/string in bytes, whereas `TYPE` will give you the size of a single array/string element.

Comment: thank you! And lastly, by chance, do you know if there is any performance/speed improvement over using the explicit numeric value?

Comment: The `TYPE` expression is evaluated at compile-time, so there's no runtime difference. In the machine code you'll have the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an assemble-time-constant integer `2`.  It assembles to `add si,2`.
**MASM `TYPE foo` is the same idea as C `sizeof(typeof(foo))`.**<sup>1</sup>

Remember in asm you have to scale from element index to byte offset yourself, e.g. increment a pointer by 2 bytes to go to the next `word`, where in C you'd just use `p++` to increment a `short *p`.

MASM also has a `sizeof` which can give you the size of a whole array, instead of just one element.

---

Normally you'd use `add si, type some_array_name` so your increment code could automatically change if you change the array to `dw` vs. `db`.

Although in that case it's somewhat pointless if you also use `AX` instead of `AL` in other instructions that actually load or store from/to `[SI]`.

You could use `type foo` as part of some other expression to calculate a size or loop bound, though.

---

Footnote 1: C/C++ doesn't actually have a `typeof` keyword; that's a GNU C extension.  But the name is more self explanatory than the standard C++11 keyword [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) which does the same thing.